# BLE app is suspended when running in Background on iOS 12

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ios12, ios-background-mode

**Background**

I have an iOS app which scans for BLE devices in the Background. It worked well until I updated to iOS12. This is what I have:

1. App is configured to run in Background (e.g. location & bluetooth-central keys in .plist)
2. App is supposed to run continuously in Background, scanning for Peripherals. This is not to be confused with Background Fetch, which is a different use case.
3. App does **not** connect to Peripherals. It only reads the advertisement packets.
4. App gets suspended after running for a few hours in the Background.
5. App resumes normal operation when brought to the Foreground
6. App operated properly in iOS 11. Problems started after updating to iOS 12.x

I placed log messages in the App Delegate methods. This last thing I see is the app entering Background State. I never see a call to `applicationWillTerminate()`, as it is only called when the app is in the Foreground.

I have seen other posts (e.g. [iOS 12 terminates apps in the background for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005174/ios-12-terminates-apps-in-the-background-for-no-reason)) for similar behavior with the Location stack. Using the test app written by the author of the post, I verified the problem has been fixed in iOS 12 for Location Services. But the BLE problems persist.

Has anyone found a workaround for this problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which service CBUUIDs are you scanning for? (What are you passing to scanForPeripherals?) Provided you're using the interface correctly, I expect you'll wind up doing the same thing the linked answer discusses, and open a defect at bugreport.apple.com to discuss it.

Comment: @RobNapier I am scanning for "0xFDnn" which is a 16 bit UUID purchased by my firm. Thanks for the heads up. I will start the dance with Apple today....

Comment: Yeah, that sounds absolutely fine; likely a related to bug to the one you linked.