# iOS 13.2 message: nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request

Tags: ios, networking, background, wifi, ios13.2

My app uses locationservices for tracking and geofencing in the background.

Now with iOS 13.2 I see every second the following message in the console:

```
Anchorwatch nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request
```

My app does nothing with the WiFi system and when I disable WiFi on the device the message disappears.

While there seem to be no adverse effects by the message I learned the hard way that ignoring message might be a bad idea.

Can anyone hint me to why this message is coming and what I can do to supress it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It eventually turned out, that a third party framework that my app uses, launches those calls to CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo.

After I added WiFi access capabilities as described [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/wifi-permission-changes-for-ios-12-1-iphone-x-and-other-devices-c313e24f90ae) to the app itself the error message disappeared

Answer (score 12):

I've managed to make it on iOS 13.3. Here goes how I make it.
(EDIT Aug/2020: I've tested this on iOS 13.6 and worked same)

The official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo) of CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo says that the function is providing real SSID/BSSID of current connection if the app

- has an "Access WiFi Information Entitlement" (see [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/wifi-permission-changes-for-ios-12-1-iphone-x-and-other-devices-c313e24f90ae)) and
- is one of 1) Core Location , 2) using NEHotspotConfiguration to connect current Wi-Fi Network, and 3) VPN app.

I've already configured "Access WiFi Information Entitlement", therefore only meet the first requirement. It does work on iOS 13.1 but doesn't work on iOS 13.3. To meet the latter requirement, I decided to include the Core Location in my APP. I've checked the code in [here](https://gist.github.com/malcommac/9abd795779a43a0d98ca704d1c4b2778) but I gotta to add some constants below on my app's Info.plist to avoid error.

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application requires user’s location for better user experience.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application requires user’s location for better user experience.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application requires user’s location for better user experience.</string>
```

I also needed to call

`manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`

before

`manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`

to popup the dialog when user launch the app for the first time.

User needed to allow the permission at the first launch. If it is allowed as "Always", the app can use CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo without error.

Answer (score 6):

Check out WWDC 19 session 713, It happenes because in iOS13 in order to get WiFi details you should allow location permission, each time you try to pull CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo data from CNCopySupportedInterfaces array you will get this log.

silly solution may be to try to enable location permission and you will not get this error anymore

Comment: Yes, I know that. But my app does already use the location services and thus has of course location permissions. My app does not call the networkinfo directly, but it seems the locations service does.

Comment: In my case it works fine after I gave the location permission!

Answer (score 0):

As [user784625 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818768/13572972) this video solved the problem for me. I hadn't realised that if using `NEHotspotConfiguration`, you can only get back values if the active network is one that you have configured in `NEHotspotConfiguration`. This is preferable to requesting location permissions if all you need is to confirm that you've connected to the configured network.

[Link to the WWDC session/timestamp](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/713/?time=3254)