# How to fetch SSID in iOS device with iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13, ssid

I have an Objective-C iPhone application and Currently I am using below code to get the connected Wifi name. But it is not working in iOS 13. How can I get the connected Wifi SSID in iOS 13?

Currently I am using the below code in Swift:

```
public class SSID {
class func fetch() -> String {
    var currentSSID = ""
    if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
        for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interfaces) {
            let interfaceName = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, i)
            let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
            let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString)
            if let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as? [String: AnyObject] {
                currentSSID = interfaceData["SSID"] as! String
                let BSSID = interfaceData["BSSID"] as! String
                let SSIDDATA = interfaceData["SSIDDATA"] as! String
                debugPrint("ssid=\(currentSSID), BSSID=\(BSSID), SSIDDATA=\(SSIDDATA)")
            }
        }
    }
    return currentSSID
  }
}
```

But this code is returning nil in iOS 13, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code provided on iOS 14 I got the following error:

`nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request`

Searching for that error took me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58791035/7245977)

[Solution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo):

> The requesting app must meet one of the following requirements:
>
> The app uses Core Location, and has the user’s authorization to use
> location information.
>
> The app uses the NEHotspotConfiguration API to configure the current
> Wi-Fi network.
>
> The app has active VPN configurations installed.
>
> An app that fails to meet any of the above requirements receives the
> following return value:
>
> An app linked against iOS 12 or earlier receives a dictionary with
> pseudo-values. In this case, the SSID is Wi-Fi (or WLAN in the China
> region), and the BSSID is 00:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> An app linked against iOS 13 or later receives NULL.
>
> Important
>
> **To use this function, an app linked against iOS 12 or later** must
> enable the Access WiFi Information capability in Xcode.

I also confirmed that this in fact works on iOS 14 once you request location permission.

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
  }

  func getWiFiName() -> String? {
    var ssid: String?

    if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
      for interface in interfaces {
        if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
          ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
          break
        }
      }
    }

    return ssid
  }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedAlways {
      let ssid = self.getWiFiName()
      print("SSID: \(String(describing: ssid))")
    }
  }
}
```

Output: `SSID: YaMomsWiFi`

Don't forget to include the wifi entitlement, and the necessary keys in your plist for location permission.

Comment: Starting from iOS 14 , this *CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo* is deprecated , no ? see : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo

Comment: are you sure as official apple developer says its deprecated in iOS14 ?

Comment: On iOS 14 you should use this instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork/3666511-fetchcurrentwithcompletionhandle